# Is there a name for, or way to describe, the music used during the 'learning to fly' scene in Avatar?

Tags: film-techniques, soundtrack, avatar

I believe the non-diegetic music I'm referring to is the song *Jake's First Flight*, composed by James Horner. The scene during which it is played reflects Jake Sully's first unaided ikran flight (in James Cameron's *Avatar*, 2009).

'Learning to fly' scenes have been discussed in relation to various films, and often incorporate some diegetic sound from the protagonist, emphasising their inexperience yet introducing character development.

The music in this scene reminds me of that used in similar scenes of other films. It is music that reflects progress and the acquisition of new skills, but it is difficult to put into words how the music itself evokes these connotations.

**Is there a name for this style of film music, or the way in which it is used in 'learning to fly' scenes?**

Answer (score 1):

In Soundtrack on spotify this track is identified as **Jake's First Flight**. This song is basically derived from **Traditional African Region's** folk music. Which was given a bit fusion touch with some modern instruments along with the old one.

So in short these type of soundtracks are called as **Fusion Music**.

> i.e : Wakanda's Theme(Black Panther), Simba's Theme (The Lion King)